# BASH output column formatting

Tags: bash, formatting

First time posting. HELLO WORLD. Working on my first script that just simply checks if a list of my websites are online and then returns the HTTP code and the amount of time it took to return that to another file on my desktop.

-- THIS SCRIPT WILL BE RUNNING ON MAC OSX --

I would like to amend my script so that it formats its output into 3 neat columns.

currently

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/Users/USER12/Desktop/url-list.txt"
printf "" > /Users/USER12/Desktop/url-results.txt
while read line
do
    printf "$line" >> /Users/USER12/Desktop/url-results.txt
    printf "\t\t\t\t" >> /Users/USER12/Desktop/url-results.txt
    curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code} %{time_total}' "$line" >> /Users/USER12/Desktop/url-results.txt
    printf "\n" >> /Users/USER12/Desktop/url-results.txt
done <"$file"
```

which outputs in the following format

```
google.com              200 0.389
facebook.com                200 0.511
abnormallyLongDomain.com                200 0.786
```

but i would like to format into neat aligned columns for easy reading

```
DOMAIN_NAME                 HTTP_CODE   RESPONSE_TIME
google.com                  200         0.389
facebook.com                200         0.511
abnormallyLongDomain.com    200         0.486
```

Thanks for the help everyone!!

Comment: Check out the `column` command.

Answer (score 13):

`column` is very nice.  You are, however, already using `printf` which gives you fine control over the output format.  Using `printf`'s features also allows the code to be somewhat simplified:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/Users/USER12/Desktop/url-list.txt"
log="/Users/USER12/Desktop/url-results.txt"
fmt="%-25s%-12s%-12s\n"
printf "$fmt" DOMAIN_NAME HTTP_CODE RESPONSE_TIME > "$log"
while read line
do
    read code time < <(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code} %{time_total}' "$line")
    printf "$fmt" "$line" "$code" "$time" >> "$log"
done <"$file"
```

With the above defined format, the output looks like:

```
DOMAIN_NAME              HTTP_CODE   RESPONSE_TIME
google.com               301         0.305
facebook.com             301         0.415
abnormallyLongDomain.com 000         0.000
```

You can fine-tune the output format, such as spacing or alignment, by changing the `fmt` variable in the script.

#### Further Refinements

The above code opens and closes the log file with each loop.  This can be avoided as Charles Duffy suggests, simply by using `exec` to redirect `stdout` to the log file before the first `printf` statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/Users/USER12/Desktop/url-list.txt"
exec >"/Users/USER12/Desktop/url-results.txt"
fmt="%-25s%-12s%-12s\n"
printf "$fmt" DOMAIN_NAME HTTP_CODE RESPONSE_TIME
while read line
do
    read code time < <(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code} %{time_total}' "$line")
    printf "$fmt" "$line" "$code" "$time"
done <"$file"
```

Alternatively, as Chepner suggests, the print statements can be grouped:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/Users/USER12/Desktop/url-list.txt"
fmt="%-25s%-12s%-12s\n"
{
printf "$fmt" DOMAIN_NAME HTTP_CODE RESPONSE_TIME
while read line
do
    read code time < <(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code} %{time_total}' "$line")
    printf "$fmt" "$line" "$code" "$time"
done <"$file"
} >"/Users/USER12/Desktop/url-results.txt"
```

An advantage of grouping is that, after the group, stdout is automatically restored to its normal value.

Comment: Better, but why not just `exec >"$log"` once and not need to do any per-command redirects at all? And, of course, you get the efficiency benefits of not re-opening the same file over and over.

Comment: Another way to avoid re-opening `"$log"` each time you try to write to it: put *all* commands that will write to it inside one command group: `{ printf "$fmt" ...; while read line; do ...; done; } < "$file" > "$log"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for showing me another way to go about this. I have implemented the second version that you have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Shortened a bit

```
#!/bin/bash

file="./url.txt"
fmt="%s\t%s\t%s\n"
( printf "$fmt" "DOMAIN_NAME" "HTTP_CODE" "RESPONSE_TIME"
while read -r line
do
    printf "$fmt" "$line" $(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code} %{time_total}' "$line")
done <"$file" ) | column -t > ./out.txt
```

Don't need redirect every `printf` but you can enclose the part of your script into `(...)` and run it in an subshell a redirect it's output. Print every field separated with one tab and use the `column` command to format it nicely.

Anyway, usually is better don't put filenames (nor headers) into the script and reduce it to

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$line" $(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code} %{time_total}' "$line")
done | column -t
```

and use it like:

```
myscript.sh < url-list.txt >result.txt
```

this allows you use your script in pipes, like:

```
something_produces_urls | myscript.sh | grep 200 > somewhere.txt
```