# Bash IF statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

rather noobie question here.. i think. but i cant get this script to work. It is going to be included inside a script that i asked about here a few days ago ([BASH output column formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130909/bash-output-column-formatting)). basically i want to be able to scrape a site for a portion of text and return a ONLINE/OFFLINE answer. I apologize for poor formatting and weird variable names. Thanks for taking a look and helping me out!

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "" > /Users/USER12/Desktop/domainQueryString_output.txt
domainCurlRequest="curl https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl"
ifStatementConditional="grep 'google.com' /Users/USER12/Desktop/domainQueryString_output.txt | wc -l"
echo $($domainCurlRequest) >> /Users/USER12/Desktop/domainQueryString_output.txt
    if [ $ifStatementConditional -eq 2 ] ; 
        then second_check="online"
    else second_check="DOMAIN IS OFFLINE"
    fi
echo $second_check
```

i keep getting the following error when trying to run this script

```
/Users/USER12/Desktop/domain_status8working.sh: line 6: [: too many arguments
```

i tried to rewrite another way but got same errors so my logic or syntax or something is off.

Thanks again for taking a look and helping me out!!!

Comment: It's possible you just need to wrap your curl statement with `$()` instead of with double-quotes

Answer (score 2):

> ifStatementConditional="grep 'google.com' /Users/USER12/Desktop/domainQueryString_output.txt | wc -l"

This is a string assignment. You probably want backticks, or the $() construct. Otherwise, *$ifStatementConditional* will never equal 2

Comment: thank you. exactly what my issue was. thanks! @CodeGnome

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ $ifStatementConditional -eq 2 ] ;
```

This is expanded as:

```
if [ grep 'google.com' /Users/USER12/Desktop/domainQueryString_output.txt | wc -l -eq 2 ] ;
```

Which explains your error.

I think you meant that:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl" > /Users/USER12/Desktop/domainQueryString_output.txt
ifStatementConditional=$("grep 'google.com' /Users/USER12/Desktop/domainQueryString_output.txt | wc -l")

    if [ $ifStatementConditional -eq 2 ] ; then 
      second_check="online"
    else 
      second_check="DOMAIN IS OFFLINE"
    fi
echo $second_check
```

1. No need to do `printf "" > somefile.txt` when you do a curl after, and you append to that file
2. `$()` is to capture subshell output. That what was missing here.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the redundant printf statement that i had in there. Much appreciated! @NoDataFound